# Bash script is not maching regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk, wsl-2, version-numbering

I truly don't understand what I'm missing here.
I have a very basic script that need to check if text contains only number (more specific a semantic version for an app), then do some stuff.

The text.txt is something like this:

`appVersion: 2.0.1`

and this is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
appVersion=`cat test.txt | awk '/^appVersion:/{print $2}'`
echo "appVersion is " $appVersion
Version=3.1.5

if [[ $appVersion =~ [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}$ ]] ; then
    echo "is a number" $appVersion 
 else
    echo "not a number" $appVersion 
fi`
```

Basically I `cat` from the text what I need, and then trying to pass that info in an if condition.

The problem is the script is basically not taking the variable `appVersion` every time I run it, it keep saying that there isn't any number in my variable, like is not matching the regex, but if I pass the variable `$Version` the script works.

By the way the echo "appVersion is " $appVersion is working (it's printing what I run inside appVersion), so the command inside my variable $appVersion is actually retrieving what I need.

I think I'm missing something with awk but I cannot understand what.

Edit:

I'm running this script on my local pc, on wsl2 ubuntu 20, as a test, to let then run it on linux azure devops agent

Comment: Can you show output of `declare -p appVersion`

Comment: Where does `test.txt` come from? Is it actually a YAML file, a TOML file, some other kind of structured file? You nearly always want to use a tool designed to parse structured text, rather than trying to cobble together a regex-based solution.

Comment: What about _(?:[0-9]\.?)+_ ... ?  This would match, _123, 1.2.3, 12.3, 1.23, 1.2.3.4,_ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
appVersion=`cat test.txt | awk '/^appVersion:/{print $2}'`
```

with

```
appVersion=$(awk '/^appVersion:/{print $2}' test.txt | dos2unix)
```

or with GNU `awk`

```
appVersion=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n"} /^appVersion:/{print $2}' test.txt)
```

to convert Windows' carriage-returns.

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, **RS**, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: I'm running this script in local on my wsl2 and I don't have dos2unix installed.

Comment: whit this one 
appVersion=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n"} /^appVersion:/{print $2}' test.txt)
is actually working but I dont get why

Comment: @Car_mine Your text file has DOS/Windows line endings, which cause all sorts of problems with unix tools. In this case, you're getting a mostly-invisible carriage return character at the end of `$appVersion`, which is not a valid part of a version number, so it causes a match failure. See ["Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525) and ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571)

Comment: ... so install it?

Comment: multi-char RS as in `RS="\r\n"` is a non-standard extension so if you're writing a script that you'll test on one machine before running it on another machine and expecting it to work then YMMV.  You should stick to POSIX standard constructs for that, e.g. `awk '/^appVersion:/{sub(/\r$/,""); print $2}'`, see the URLs @GordonDavisson already provided for more info.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you for pointing this out. I added `with GNU awk` to my question to clarify the safe area of application.

Comment: Thanks, guys to point this out, I was looping around the POSIX and carriage return but I was not able to understand it properly.